# Ubuntu 20.04 software update issues: lost resolution, no internet, extra lines on grub page

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, updates, display-resolution

Ubuntu notified me that a software update was available, and that I would need to reboot to complete the update. I went for it. I was told that the updates had downloaded, and was given the option to install. After selecting install (twice), and getting back to the same options, I decided to reboot. Bad choice.

The resolution was terrible. Power cycling didn't help. Also no internet. And there were a couple of lines extra lines on the grub page: Instead of replacing the Ubuntu and Ubuntu (Advanced Options) lines, new lines were added.

Aside: I also dual boot into windows.

I booted using an "advanced option" - using the previous kernel: 5.11.0.38 . . . , if that is right terminology. Resolution good, internet works.

Suggested repairs?

Clue: I tried updating and upgrading, and . . .

```
tscale:~$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04-edge/focal-updates,focal-security 5.13.0-21.21~20.04.1+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it

tscale:~$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
[sudo] password for tscale: 
Listing... Done
linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04-edge/focal-updates,focal-security 5.13.0-21.21~20.04.1+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1]
linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04-edge/now 5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.13.0-21.21~20.04.1+1]
```

Thanks,
Tim

"nobody" asked if I could add the following to my question:

tscale:~$ uname -r
5.11.0-40-generic

tscale:~$ dkms status
nvidia, 460.91.03, 5.11.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 460.91.03, 5.11.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 460.91.03, 5.4.0-90-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: can you add `dkms status` also `uname -r` to your question please?

Comment: To be sure please reinstall kernel headers by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-40 linux-headers-5.11.0-40-generic` and then try to reboot with this 5.11.40 kernel.

Comment: N0rbert: I did as you suggested. Soft and hard reboot. No change.

Comment: Is there a (ubuntu?) target group/person that might be able to tell me how to clean up the seemingly botched update?

Comment: N0rbert: I just re-looked at your suggestion, and I did indeed run the command you suggested. But my next action was to try to boot 5.13.0-21, and that failed, as described. I can boot with 5.11.0-40, which is the one you suggested I reinstall. Is there a similar command to either get 5.13.0-21 working? Or get right of its grub entry? Thanks, Tim